# UICollectionView lags when scrolling due to data retrieved from parse query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm developing an iOS application with Parse as Backend.
I have this query to retrieve some data from server and populate a collection view

```
let getAncmntsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Announcement")
    getAncmntsQuery.whereKey("categories", equalTo: self.category.objectId!)
    getAncmntsQuery.includeKey("user")
    getAncmntsQuery.order(byDescending: "startDate")
    if let currentUser = PFUser.current() {
        getAncmntsQuery.whereKey("user", notEqualTo: currentUser)
    }
    getAncmntsQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (result, error) in
        if error == nil{
            self.collectionView.backgroundView = nil
            self.ancmnts = result as? [Announcement]
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
       }
   }
```

and this is cellForItemAt

```
cell.phoneNumber = ancmnts[indexPath.row].phoneNumber
    cell.title = ancmnts[indexPath.row].title
    cell.price = "\(ancmnts[indexPath.row].price)"
    cell.objectId = ancmnts[indexPath.row].objectId
    cell.ancmntImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.videoMark.isHidden = true
    cell.ancmntTitle.text = ancmnts[indexPath.row].title
    cell.ancmntPrice.text = "\(ancmnts[indexPath.row].price) TND"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: ancmnts[indexPath.row].startDate as Date)
    cell.ancmntDate.text = dateString
    if !ancmnts[indexPath.row].videoUrl.isEmpty {
        cell.ancmntImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: ancmnts[indexPath.row].thumbnailUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"nophoto"), options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            if image != nil {
                cell.ancmntImage.image = imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize(originalImage: image!, size: cell.ancmntImage.frame.size)
                cell.videoMark.isHidden = false
            }
        })

    }else if ancmnts[indexPath.row].picturesUrl.count > 0 {

        cell.ancmntImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: ancmnts[indexPath.row].picturesUrl[0]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"nophoto"), options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            cell.ancmntImage.image = imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize(originalImage: image!, size: cell.ancmntImage.frame.size)
        })
    }else{
        cell.ancmntImage.image = UIImage(named: "nophoto")
        cell.ancmntImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.videoMark.isHidden = true
    }
    if self.ancmnts?[indexPath.row].user["avatarUrl"] != nil {
        cell.ownerPhoto.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.ancmnts?[indexPath.row].user["avatarUrl"] as! String), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"avatar"), options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            cell.ownerPhoto.image = imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize(originalImage: image!, size: cell.ownerPhoto.frame.size)
        })
    }else{
        cell.ownerPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
    }

    cell.ownerName.text = self.ancmnts?[indexPath.row].user["username"] as? String
```

The problem is the scroll of collection view lags when I comment the part of code in cellForItemAt related to "user" which is included in the query

```
getAncmntsQuery.includeKey("user")
```

the scroll of uicollectionview is returned to normal state,so the "user" included is blocking the scroll, i'm trying to loop through the "result" array of parse query and prepare another array of PFUser which contain all the users in "result" but same problem remained. my question is how to solve this? is this related to main thread i'm blocking it, if so what is the solution? using background thread in cellForItemAt?

Comment: How big are your avatar images?  By omitting the user key you won't have any avatars. My suspicion is that scaling the avatar image may be taking some time, but you can use the time profiler instrument to confirm.

Comment: Parse, as in Parse.com ? Isn't that service down since January?

Comment: I think Parse is going to shutdown soon

Comment: parse server hosted in my own server

Comment: Parse.com shut down their hosted service, but open sourced their platform so you can host your own instance.

Comment: There may be some gained optimizations if you were to use PFCollectionViewCells instead, from the iOS SDK: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFCollectionViewCell.html